# Identify Image with solid Color

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, image-processing, core-image

I am working in a scenario in which I have two images one with a solid colour background and another with an object eg(butterfly, pen, etc) is there anyway to identify the image has solid colour background or it has an object in it, can anyone give some idea.

example images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When using Core Image, you can use the `CIAreaMinMax` filter to compute the minimum and maximum color component values among all pixels in the image and then compare them. If they are the same, that means that the image only has one solid color.

Here is also an equivalent Metal Performance Shader: `MPSImageStatisticsMinAndMax`